# Create Holo-like theme for Android inputs using css

Tags: css

Is there a way to get this type of inputs:

[image: Holo theme]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Mi2BW-8T8eY/TwNpdVemR_I/AAAAAAAABAc/-oOTaZ5M4_A/s400/Screenshot_2011-11-17-22-23-18.png))</sub>

mimicked in css without using images?

I've tried creating a css triangle but I can't make it work there using this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ and the only other solution I think of is an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can somehow emulate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vhcw/

```
<span class="holo"><input type="text" /></span>
```

```css
span.holo > input[type='text'] {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding:0px;
}
span.holo {
    border-bottom:solid 1px blue;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:1px 0px;
}
span.holo:after,
span.holo::after {
    content:' ';
    overflow:hidden;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:99%;
    bottom:-1px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:solid 5px transparent;
    border-bottom-color:blue;
    border-right-color:blue;
}
```

Tested only on Chrome desktop and Palemoon (Firefox desktop fork) though.

The weird `left:99%` is because there will be one pixel margin if `left:100%` is used (on Chrome desktop). If you don't mind using `calc()`, you can add

```css
left:99%;
left:-webkit-calc(100% - 1px);
left:-moz-calc(100% - 1px);
left:calc(100% - 1px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vhcw/1/

**Edit**:

Just realized that I can use `padding` to "include" the triangle into the `span`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vhcw/2/

```css
span.holo {
    padding-right:10px;
}
span.holo:after,
span.holo::after {
    right:0px;
}
```

**Edit** #2:

Fine-tuned to "fix" the weird `bottom:-1px`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vhcw/3/

```css
span.holo {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
span.holo:after,
span.holo::after {
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Also for the explanation I was trying to do it in the input element not in a span, any specific reason for doing that?

Comment: @LuisArmando The main reason is that I don't seem to be able to get `:after` work with `<input type="text">` :)